# .htaccess mod_rewrite + $_GET not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following mod_rewrite line (it's the only line in the .htaccess file). It works when I change the first name to something other than `login`, but for some reason fails to pass the `$_GET['initials']` when it's the same name as the actual script. Is it somehow overwriting its own rewrite?

```
RewriteRule ^login/([a-z]{1,5}) login.php?initials=$1 [L]
```

Edit:

Looking at $_SERVER, this is the page that PHP ends up loading:

```
'PHP_SELF' => string '/admin/login.php/abc' (length=19)
```

where 'abc' is the intitials provided. So it's dropping the query string completely and trying to load that page, which somehow loads login.php and not a 404 even though the /abc directory doesn't exist?

Comment: does adding a $ work? `RewriteRule ^login/([a-z]{1,5})$ login.php?initials=$1 [L]` do you have a `RewriteBase /` set?

Comment: No that still fails.. I don't have RewriteBase set, first time I've heard of it..

Comment: It's worth noting this .htaccess is in a subdirectory, not the base apache directory.

Comment: This is an example one I use; `RewriteRule ^order/([a-z0-9])$ /retailer/order.php?order_ref=$1` with `RewriteEngine On` and `RewriteBase /retailer/` and that works for me with /order/order where the second order is the order_ref, so yours SHOULD work... Perhaps try `RewriteBase /subdirectory/` (before the rewriterule) and then change `login.php` to `/subdirectory/login.php` ?

Comment: SOLVED: MultiViews was on in the site's configuration file, which was automatically adding the .php file extension onto 'login'. Fixed by setting "-Multiviews" in the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /SUBDIRECTORY_NAME_HERE/
RewriteRule ^login/([^/]*)/$ /login.php?initials=$1 [L]
```

May help also if you add the sub directory in front of login.php.

```
RewriteRule ^login/([^/]*)/$ /SUBDIRECTORY_NAME_HERE/login.php?initials=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is in the comments above but it does not really tell you what to do.

`Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /SUBDIRECTORY_NAME_HERE/
RewriteRule ^login/([^/]*)/$ /login.php?initials=$1 [L]`